# Changing from non linear to linear using Big M

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I have a binary variable $v_{ij}$ and integer variable $c_{ijk}$ and the following relationship:

$$
c_{ijk} \le M \; v_{ij}
$$

$M$ is a very large number

Is there a way to change this nonlinear constraint to a linear constraint?

Comment: What is Big M in your question?

Comment: Big M is a very large number.

Comment: This is linear...

Comment: I'm modeling this in LINGO but it says that it's not linear...

Comment: If $c$ and $v$ are variables, and $M$ is defined as a constant, then it is linear. Maybe you declared $M$ as a variable ?